# Is there a way to deserialize an unknown object with a DescriptorProto?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I want to find a way to deserialize an unknown object with a DescriptorProto. When I serialize a *Person*, it's not a problem because I know its type. But when I deserialize, I don't know the type of object I receive so how with DescriptorProto, which define the structure of the proto, I can create an object like an ExpandObject?

This is my class :

```
    class Person
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

I create an object Person with some values, serialize it and create my .proto :

```
var person = new Person
{
   Id = 12345,
   Name = "Fred"
};
using (var file = File.Create(@"C:\temp\protobuf\person.bin"))
{
   Serializer.Serialize(file, person);
   file.SetLength(file.Position);
}
string proto = Serializer.GetProto<Person>();
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\protobuf\person.proto", proto);
```

After i create my FileDescriptor with this following command line :

```
protoc.exe person.proto --descriptor_set_out=person.pb
```

Finally i want to deserialize my **person.bin** with the description of **person.pb** like this :

```
byte[] payload = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\temp\protobuf\person.pb");
FileDescriptorSet fileDescriptorSet = FileDescriptorSet.ParseFrom(payload);
FileDescriptorProto fileDescriptorProto = fileDescriptorSet.GetFile(0);
DescriptorProto requestDescriptor = fileDescriptorProto.GetMessageType(0);

/**
             requestDescriptor : 

            {name: "Person"
                field {
                  name: "Id"
                  number: 1
                  label: LABEL_OPTIONAL
                  type: TYPE_INT32
                  default_value: "0"
                }
                field {
                  name: "Name"
                  number: 2
                  label: LABEL_OPTIONAL
                  type: TYPE_STRING
                }
             }

             **/

object youhou;
using (var file = File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\protobuf\person.bin"))
{
    //youhou = Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(file);
    // I don't know **Person** so i can't do this
}
```

At first, I wanted to create a **Dictionary of string, object** instead of **Person** but it's impossible to serialize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering this **specifically** from the perspective of protobuf-net (tags); if you use the Google C# API, things will be different.

There's a couple of different things here; protobuf-net does not currently have an API to load things *specifically* taking a descriptor, however! It  *does* have an `Extensible` base class which can be used to deserialize any arbitrary payload, along with the `static` methods on `Extensible` such as `Extensible.GetValue<int>(1)`. So; that gives you the ability to read (or write) an arbitrary payload. You might need to create a non-abstract class to play with, but `class Foo : Extensible {}` should suffice, then `Serializer.Deserialize<Foo>(source)`.

So; the second part is how to parse a descriptor. For that, see the [`protobuf-net.Reflection`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/protobuf-net.Reflection/) package. This includes the usual descriptor types you would expect, including `FileDescriptorSet`, so: you can use protobuf-net's regular `Serializer.Deserialize<FileDescriptorSet>(source)` to get a descriptor-set, from which you can pull apart the model in the usual way and discover the properties, to use with `Extensible`.

Comment: Yes I discover today that I mix protobuf-net and the Google C# API. Thanks for your answer, i will take a look at Extensible base class cause for me it will probably answer at my problem.