# Deserialize unknown object with protobuf-net knowing the schema

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have to parse back message of unknown type, serialized by protobuf-net.

I have succesfully parsed back FileDescriptorSet from raw bytes, I mean I know type name, it's fields etc. But how to deserialize message back withouth knowing it's type? [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56143512/is-there-a-way-to-deserialize-an-unknown-object-with-a-descriptorproto) and Marc's answer is close, but I fail to understand how to use Extensible class.

> You might need to create a non-abstract class to play with, but class
> Foo : Extensible {} should suffice, then
> Serializer.Deserialize(source).

So I dont have "Foo", I have only FileDescriptorSet and serialized bytes of message. I need to do it in code "on-the-fly". How to marry FileDescriptorSet  with byte array, containing values of unknown message type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *simple* answer to this question, and I haven't yet had need to fully implement an example. The only thing `Extensible` does for us here is allow basic access to ad-hoc fields still stored as bytes. So: you can deserialize an `Extensible` from your data source, and then use `Extensible.GetValue<Type>(obj, fieldNumber)` and the associated overloads of that API. You would need to do this based on your *own* interpretation of the `DescriptorProto` that you're looking at (a `DescriptorProto` is a type inside a `FileDescriptorSet`). For example, you might enumerate `.Fields`, and for each: infer some `<T>` from the `.type` and `.TypeName` (which you would have to resolve to another `DescriptorProto` or `EnumDescriptorProto` etc), and the `.Number` (for the tag). For any message type, you can just use `Extensible` again and repeat the process recursively. You'd also need to check the `.Label` to see if it is repeated, and if so: use `Extensible.GetValues<T>` instead.

That's the theory. I haven't had the need to put it into practice.

Comment: I understand almost everything except deserializing Extensible. If I try to use Serializer.Deserialize<Extensible>(input_message_bytes) ; it gives me an Exception "Type is not expected, and no contract can be inferred: ". To use GetValue method I have to get Extensible instance somehow.

Comment: @Michael `[ProtoContract] public sealed class UseThisInstead : Extensible {}`